# Why does manually iterating work but not a for loop?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I have been working on some distance functions for a fractal in WebGL and noticed that whenever I set an iteration count to be 3 or greater it fails on my computer. By that I mean that I get a gray screen instead of a gray scale fractal (which I think suggests that the calculation is not completing because I have tested it for correctness in a non-WebGL setting)

However, on a machine at work it works just fine at counts of 3 or greater. I define the number of iterations like this:

```
#define MANDELBOX_ITER 20
```

Trying to figure out the problem I converted my iteration based code:

```
float mandelboxDist(Object inMandelbox, vec3 inPos) {
    inPos -= inMandelbox.pos;
    vec3 offset = vec3(inPos);

    float d = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MANDELBOX_ITER; i++) {
        // Boxfold
        inPos = clamp(inPos, -MANDELBOX_BFOLD, MANDELBOX_BFOLD)*2.0-inPos;

        // Spherefold
        float posDot = dot(inPos, inPos);
        if (posDot < MANDELBOX_MIN_RAD) {
            inPos *= MANDELBOX_LINEAR_SCALE;
            d *= MANDELBOX_LINEAR_SCALE;
        }
        else if (posDot < MANDELBOX_FIXED_RAD) {
            float inversion = MANDELBOX_FIXED_RAD/posDot;
            inPos *= inversion;
            d *= inversion;
        }

        inPos = MANDELBOX_SCALE*inPos+offset;
        d = MANDELBOX_SCALE*d+1.0;
    }

    return length(inPos)/abs(d);
}
```

...into this:

```
void iterateMandelbox(inout vec3 pos, vec3 inOffset, inout float d) {
    // Boxfold
    pos = clamp(pos, -MANDELBOX_BFOLD, MANDELBOX_BFOLD)*2.0-pos;

    // Spherefold
    float posDot = dot(pos, pos);
    if (posDot < MANDELBOX_MIN_RAD) {
        pos *= MANDELBOX_LINEAR_SCALE;
        d *= MANDELBOX_LINEAR_SCALE;
    }
    else if (posDot < MANDELBOX_FIXED_RAD) {
        float inversion = MANDELBOX_FIXED_RAD/posDot;
        pos *= inversion;
        d *= inversion;
    }

    pos = MANDELBOX_SCALE*pos+inOffset;
    d = MANDELBOX_SCALE*d+1.0;
}

float mandelboxDist(Object inMandelbox, vec3 inPos) {
    inPos -= inMandelbox.pos;
    vec3 offset = vec3(inPos);
    float d = 1.0;

    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);
    iterateMandelbox(inPos, offset, d);

    return length(inPos)/abs(d);
}
```

...and found that is works on my computer. Obviously this is extremely inconvenient, and I have no idea why it works when "manually" looping. What is going on?

**Edit**: In response to LJ_1102's answer, I have a Macbook from 2011 and "About This Mac" tells me I have an "Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB" graphics card

Answer (score 1):

In assumption that you're on a windows pc it sounds like you're experiencing a loop unrolling bug in [ANGLE](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/).

To verify this start your browser with `--use-gl=desktop`. This flag forces your browser to *not use* the ANGLE DirectX conversion layer. When your problem is indeed ANGLE based
take a look at the compiled HLSL code using [getTranslatedShaderSource](http://www.ianww.com/2013/01/14/debugging-angle-errors-in-webgl-on-windows/) and debug from there.

Unfortunately if it is an angle based issue your only chance to get it running is either fiddling around until its converted correctly or file a bug on the angle project page.

Comment: I actually have a Macbook, maybe I should have written this above. If it matters, it is from 2011 and "About This Mac" tells me I have an "Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB" graphics card

Comment: Yes it does, I'm assuming you're running OSX on that Macbook then? As far as i remember there were some issues with the (Intel HD 3000) drivers, do you have the most recent version of OSX installed, what does [chrome://gpu/](chrome://gpu/)/[about:gpu](about:gpu) (assuming you're using chrome) gives you, are any driver workarounds applied? Also you may want to have a go on the [WebGL Conformance Tests](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html). Your best bet though is to update your graphics drivers.

Comment: Additional to that, have you tried just using a constant instead of a define as your termination condition?

Comment: I have been doing most of my testing in Firefox, several of the conformance tests failed, and using a constant rather than a `define` did not make a difference. I think I am just going to stick with manually unrolling the loop rather than making all of those function calls, at least I know that works, thank you

Comment: Even on Mac ANGLE might be used to re-write the shader to work around issues in the driver. It might still be a good idea to take a look at the translated shader and file a bug at http://crbug.com or http://code.google.com/p/angleproject